# ID is not changing, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, web

```
function change(id) {
    var i = findpos(id);
    totalprice += (parseInt($('#' + id + '_cnt').val()) - purchased[i].cnt) * purchased[i].price;
    purchased[i].cnt = parseInt($('#' + id + '_cnt').val());
    update_total();
}
```

Comment: In the top, are declared: var purchased=new Array();
var totalprice=0;

Comment: You should edit the post to reflect those declarations instead of putting additional code into the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this function doesn't have any thing to do with a changing id. I suggest you take a closer look at the function calling this function or the HTML tags related to this function.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot for the light.